# Selecting store with multiple products

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `store` and one named `products`.

The data is structured like this:

```
Store table 
ID NAME
1, 'red fruit store';
2, 'blue fruit store';
3, 'orange fruit store';

Fruits table
ID STORE_ID PRODUCT_NAME
1, 1, 'orange';
2, 1, 'apple';
3, 1, 'banana';
4, 2, 'apple';
5, 3, 'banana';
6, 3, 'pear';

Vegetables table
ID STORE_ID PRODUCT_NAME
1, 1, 'tomato';
2, 1, 'carrot';
3, 1, 'potato';
4, 2, 'cabbage';
5, 3, 'tomato';
6, 3, 'carrot';
```

So I want to select the store that has both orange and banana from the fruits table and tomato, carrot and potato from the vegetables table.

How can I do that?

**EDIT**

If I want to select the store having

- oranges
- one or multiple from (banana, apple pear)
- and tomato or carrot

How can I do that ?

Comment: You didn't define the table alias `p` in your query. You need `LEFT JOIN products [AS] p`. Is this a typo as you copied the query to this question, or is it really how you coded it in your app?

Comment: Yes, that is a typo only in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `join` between the tables, a condition on the results like:

```
product_name in ('banana', 'orange')
```

and then `group by s.id, s.name` to get only the stores that have both 'banana' and 'orange':

```
select s.id, s.name 
from store s inner join product p
on p.store_id = s.id
where p.product_name in ('banana', 'orange')
group by s.id, s.name
having count(*) = 2
```

If you need to check for more products you will have to change the list that is checked with `in` and the number of `having count(*) = ?` to be **exactly** the number of items in the list.
Another way to get the results you want is with EXISTS:

```
select s.* from store s
where 
  exists (
    select 1 from products
    where store_id = s.id and product_name = 'orange'
  )
  and
  exists (
    select 1 from products
    where store_id = s.id and product_name = 'banana'
  )
```

**Edit**
For your edited question:

```
select s.id, s.name 
from store s
inner join fruits f on f.store_id = s.id
inner join vegetables v on v.store_id = s.id
where 
  f.product_name in ('banana', 'orange')
  and
  v.product_name in ('tomato', 'carrot', 'potato')
group by s.id, s.name
having 
  count(distinct f.id) = 2
  and 
  count(distinct v.id) = 3
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gM3CLDXbcvPNyDK5trKXaD/0).
Results:

```
| id  | name            |
| --- | --------------- |
| 1   | red fruit store |
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the store that have both the products (at least) you could use a couple of inner join

```
 SELECT s.id AS store_id, 
         s.name AS store_name
  FROM store AS s 
  INNER JOIN Products p1 ON p1.STORE_ID = s.ID AND  p1.PRODUCT_NAME = 'orange' 
  INNER JOIN Products p2 ON p2.STORE_ID = s.ID AND  p2.PRODUCT_NAME = 'banana'
```

You query fail  because there not row with both  the product so the AND fail

if you want the store with al least one of the two product  you can use left join

or you could use count of product group by store

```
SELECT s.id AS store_id, 
       s.name AS store_name
FROM store AS s 
INNER JOIN (
  select  STORE_ID 
  from Products where PRODUCT_NAME IN ('orange','banana' )
  group by STORE_ID  
  having count(distinct PRODUCT_NAME ) = 2
)
```

Comment: Is there any other way ? This one is a little-bit difficult to implement in my existing code base.

Comment: Thank you for the new suggestion. The number of PRODUCT_NAME is not always 2 can be 3 or more. So I suggest  `having count(distinct PRODUCT_NAME) > 1`

Comment: if you want that the match is strictly related to the list of product  .. the should be = 2  .. if you want that just one product  match  then you can use > 1  ..  depend  on your needs .. anyway i thinks this second answer is more easly  usable  respect the first ..